# Include current URL GET parameters in form

Tags: laravel, http, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I am using steam auth. Once a user authenticates in steam, he is redirected back to my form where I ask him for his username(my and steam username rules differ) and email(steam does not provide it).

The problem is that if input is invalid he is redirected back(via laravel request) but at that point all GET parameters from steam are lost and he needs to visit steam login page again.

Controller method that decides whether to redirect to steam or show my login form

```
public function steamLogin()
{
    if ($this->steam->validate()) {
        $info = $this->steam->getUserInfo();

        if (!is_null($info)) {
            $user = User::where('steam', $info->getSteamID64())->first();

            if (is_null($user)) {
                if (!Cache::has('steam_' . $info->getSteamID64())) {
                    Cache::put('steam_' . $info->getSteamID64(), $info, Carbon::now()->addMinutes(5));
                }

                return view('auth.steam', ['info' => $info]);
            }

            Auth::login($user, true);
            return redirect('/');
        }
    }

    return $this->steam->redirect();
}
```

It is  taken off an example [here](https://github.com/invisnik/laravel-steam-auth)

Comment: You could just redirect back with `return back();`. Does that solve the problem for you?

Comment: Laravel requests take care of redirecting, so I'm note sure how exactly does it do it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're handling the form submission?

Comment: But it never is executed because the request rules return back.

Comment: Then you're submitting the form to the wrong url. Can you append both the view/form and the function handling the submission?

Comment: I'll try to explain again. All I need is to add all GET parameters to a form. Is there an easier way to do it and not just manually pass each of them to that form and add them as a hidden input?

Comment: All right. Here's how you can redirect with your GET parameters. return `redirect()->to('/path-to-redirect?'.http_build_query(Input::query()));` or `redirect redirect()->route('route-name', Input::query());` if you have a named route.

Comment: However, I would recommend that you add them as hidden values to the form since it can be slightly troublesome handling the 'GET' query if you post the form through the 'POST' method. (assuming that's what you are doing)